# spectrum, eigenspectrum and approximate eigenspectrum for $A$.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X = l^p$ and define $$A : X \to X$$ as $$ A(\mathbf{x}) = (x_1, x_2/2, x_3/3,\dots),\ \  \mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots).$$
Find spectrum, eigenspectrum and approximate eigenspectrum for $A$.

> **Spetrum:**$$ \sigma(A)=\{k\in \mathbb{K}\ :\ A-kI\ \text{is not invertible}\} $$
>
> **Eigen Spetrum:**$$ \sigma_e(A)=\{k\in \mathbb{K}\ :\ A-kI\ \text{is not injective}\} $$
>
> **Approximate Spetrum:**$$ \sigma_a(A)=\{k\in \mathbb{K}\ :\ A-kI\ \text{is not bounded below}\} $$

Here, in this question $$(A-kI)(\mathbf{x})=\left(x_1(1-k),x_2\left(\frac{1}{2}-k\right),x_3\left(\frac{1}{3}-k\right),\dots\right).$$ Now how will I find out $k$ for the all spectrum?

Comment: The eigenspectrum is easy.  Just solve $(A-k)x=0$. To find the spectrum, observe that if $(A-k)^{-1}$ exists then $(A-k)^{-1}x=(n^{-1}-k)^{-1}\cdot x$.  When is this map bounded?

Comment: What are the possible values for $p$?

Comment: what is $p$ here?

Comment: You mentioned $X=\ell^p$.

Comment: Okay sorry, assume $1\leq p\le\infty$. Although it is not mentioned.